# d&d p:fileUpload from external program (e.g. outlook)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop

I have a **`<p:fileUpload .../>`** in my JSF 2.0-Site, and I want that the user can **Drag&Drop an Email directly from Outlook to the drop field**.

Unfortunately this leads to following error page like: "Error: Wrong URL (The URL is not valid and cannot be loaded)"

It it possible what I want to do with Primefaces p:fileupload?

my code snipplet is:

```
<h:form>

    <p:fileUpload process="@form" oncomplete="init();" id="upload" label="Choose Files" style="width:600px;" fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}" auto="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true" update="messages filetable upload" />

    <!-- ...some other stuff -->

</h:form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do you have your `p:fileUpload` defined?

Comment: <h:form><p:fileUpload process="@form" oncomplete="init();" id="upload" label="Choose Files" style="width:600px;" fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}" auto="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true" update="messages filetable upload" />...</h:form>

Comment: Please, edit your question adding your code instead of writing it into a comment.

Comment: is this not supported?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=outlook+email+drag+drop+upload Apparently not natively.

Comment: from Thunderbird it works...